# How to enable access to on-premise URL from AWS CodePipeline - CodeBuild?

Tags: sonarqube, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am new to AWS CodePipeline.
I am developing a pipeline in AWS. I used CodeBuild for building the artifacts. At the same stage I want to do SonarQube scanning for my code.

My SonarQube is installed on On-Premise Server.

When I run the pipeline I am getting :

```
SonarQube URL [http://...:9000] can't be reached
```

Please assist on how to resolve this.

BuildSpec.yml file

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - wget https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-3.3.0.1492-linux.zip
      - unzip sonar-scanner-cli-3.3.0.1492-linux.zip
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - ls
      - ./sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-linux/bin/sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=Application/sonar-project.properties
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
reports: #New
  SurefireReports: # CodeBuild will create a report group called "SurefireReports".
    files: #Store all of the files
      - '**/*'
    base-directory: 'Application/target/surefire-reports' # Location of the reports
artifacts:
  files:
    - Application/target/ROOT.jar
    - appspec.yml
    - start_server.sh
```

Comment: Is your build project using vpc configuration?

Comment: No it s not using VPC Configuration